# How to remove extra gap between items in TTSectionedDataSource under iOS5

Tags: iphone, three20

I am experiencing an extra gap between TTableTextItems in a TTSectionedDataSource under iOS5, the same code is not showing the extra space under iOS4.You can see it in image below.
, left side is IOS 4.3 and right side is iOS5.

[image]

My TTTableViewController code is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.variableHeightRows = NO;
        self.tableViewStyle = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
        self.autoresizesForKeyboard = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) createModel {
    self.dataSource = [[[NewDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
    return [[[NewTableDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

The TTTableViewDelegate code is:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 70   ;
    }
    return 200;
}
```

And my TTSectionedDataSource:

```
- (void) tableViewDidLoadModel:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [super tableViewDidLoadModel:tableView];
    [self.sections addObject:@"Section 1"];
    [self.items addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"TTTableTextItem1" URL:@""]]];
    [self.sections addObject:@"Section 2"];
    [self.items addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"TTTableTextItem 2" URL:@""]]];
}
```

The problem is happening because the method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`  in the `TTTableViewDelegate` gets called 2 times (with values 1 and 0) under iOS4 and it gets called 4 times (values 1,1,0 and 0) under iOS5 this is why I can see the extra gap between TTTableTextItems.

Any ideas of why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with the new behaviour of `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` under iOS5.

From Apple documentation:

> Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights of footers to 0 for  sections where tableView:viewForFooterInSection: returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual height for each section footer in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the entire code for the `TTSectionedDataSource`?

If you believe it's a bug related to iOS 5, you can open a github issue at https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues with as much as details as possible

Comment: I don't think it is a bug in three20 since I have some other TTSectionedDataSource and they behave correctly. I have quite a large code to post here, I will try to isolate and paste some parts. do you know of any property in the TTTableViewController or the datasource which may be adding the extra space?

Comment: I think I found the root cause of the problem, it is a method in the TTTableViewDelegate, please see my edited question.